# Python urllib2 anonymity through tor

Tags: python, sockets, urllib2, tor

I have been trying to use SocksiPy (http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/) and set my sockets with SOCKS5 and set it to go through a local tor service that I am running on my box.

I have the following:

```
socks.setdefausocks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050, True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

import urllib2
```

And I am doing something similar to:

```
workItem = "http://192.168.1.1/some/stuff" #obviously not the real url
req = urllib2.Request(workItem)
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla 5.10')
res = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=60)
```

And even using this I have been identified by the website, my understanding was that I would be coming out of a random end point every time and it wouldn't be able to identify me. And I can confirm if I hit whatsmyip.org with this that my end point is different every time. Is there some other steps I have to take to keep anonymous? I am using an IP address in the url so it shouldn't be doing any DNS resolution that might give it away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such User-Agent 'Mozilla 5.10' in reality. If the server employs even the simplest fingerprinting based on the User-Agent it will identity you based on this uncommon setting.

And I don't think you understand TOR: it does not provide full anonymity. It only helps by providing anonymity by hiding you real IP address. But it does not help if you give your real name on a web site or use such easily detectable features like an uncommon user agent.

You might have a look at the [Design and Implementation Notes](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/) for the TOR browser bundle to see what kind of additional steps they take to be less detectable and where they still see open problems. You might also read about [Device Fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) which is used to identity the seemingly anonymous peer.